# Get rid of if statement

Tags: if-statement, optimization

In code I come to situation like this:

```
if (a && b || c && d || e && f || g && h){
    // do something
}
```

Like this:

```
if len(env.workers) == 0 && env.minQueue.Len() == 0 || len(env.workers) == len(env.daemonList) && env.minQueue.Len() == 0 || len(env.workers) > 0 && len(env.workers) == len(env.daemonList) {
        env.shouldStop = true
        return nil
    }
```

But it's hard to debug and find errors. Is there any way to use more friendly constructuion to replace such statement.

Comment: Evaluate it in parts? Like in temporary intermediate variables?

Comment: Extract the condition expression into a method (the name of which conveys the logic it represents, thus making this code easier to read).  Within that method, introduce as many variables as you like to hold each part of the overall logic and express it clearly.

Comment: Put a line shift after each ´||´ and parentheses around each `&&` to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

You use `len(env.daemonList)`, `len(env.workers)` and `env.minQueue.Len()` multiple times. Storing them in variables not only shortens up that long condition, but also gives you variables that can be referenced when debugging.

You could write it as:

```
w_len = len(env.workers)
d_len = len(env.daemonList)
q_len = env.minQueue.Len()

if w_len == 0 && q_len == 0 || w_len == d_len && q_len == 0 || w_len > 0 && w_len == d_len {...
```

Now, of course the problem here is that while shorter, the names aren't as descriptive. You could give them better names at the cost of verbosity. How much you want to lean in each direction is a matter of taste and context.

This also doesn't "get rid" of the `if` like the title states, but that's not always a great goal to have. `if`s aren't necessarily bad.

Answer (score 1):

As @Eugene mentioned it's always good idea to break long expressions like this into multiple smaller expressions.

```
exp1 = a && b
exp2 = c && d
exp3 = exp1 || exp2
exp4 = e && f
exp5 = g && h
exp6 = exp4 || exp5
exp7 = exp3 || exp6

if(exp7){
   //doSomething
}
```

This may look absurd in beginning but believe me it has long way to go, at any point you can come back to the above code and easily understand what's cooking there. In fact if you like using debuggers then doing this would make your life way easier.

Also in point of performance, all you are doing is making extra 7 boolean variables. It's insignificant when code readability is concerned. And the thumb rule for better code readability is naming your variable right, not exp1,2,....